# How to align 2 or more submission buttons on the same line on a Symfony form

Tags: symfony, button, form-submit, symfony-forms

Currently starting with Symfony (v3.3), I'd like to align 2 or more buttons on the same line in a form.

Cannot find how to do that while looking the Symfony docs or forums (in fact 2 Submit buttons and 1 Reset button).

How can I align 2 or more submission buttons on the same line on a Symfony form?

Answer (score 0):

To add several submit buttons in your form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('submit1', SubmitType::class)
        ->add('submit2', SubmitType::class)
```

To know which submit is used you have to used `isClicked`

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        if ($form->get('submit2')->isClicked()) { 
        }
        if ($form->get('submit1')->isClicked()) {    
        }
    }
```

You have to render the forms_button manually

```
<div>
    {{ form_widget(form.submit1) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.submit2) }}
    <button>A buton not related to the form submission</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Both form definition (->add) and submit button isClicked are already working fine. 
The problem I have is just that the buttons are placed on subsequent / different lines. The current 'construction' of the form is embedded in a twig view like this

<div class="well">
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
</div>

Does it means I have to replace this <div> § by a manual constructor for the entire form (all fields of the form)?